# AHK: disabling PgDn & PgUp keys while running script

Tags: autohotkey

What I want to do is create a script that allows me to disable the effect of the <kbd>PgDn</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys while it waits (so it doesn't instantaneously capture the hotkey so there's no override), while not having any effect on the program in that wait duration.

Example scenario: In the 3 seconds that the <kbd>PgDn</kbd> key must be held down to activate a (say) MsgBox, it must not cause a browser window, etc. To accept the <kbd>PgDn</kbd> input. That is I don't want my webpage scrolling down while I'm pressing down the <kbd>PgDn</kbd> key.

This is my code so far.

```
~PgDn::
If PgDnIsPressed
return

PgDnIsPressed := true
SetTimer, WaitForRelease, 3000
return

~PgDn Up::
SetTimer, WaitForRelease, Off
PgDnIsPressed := false
return

WaitForRelease:
SetTimer, WaitForRelease, Off
msgbox Working
return
```

It works, but not without scrolling the webpage in any way.

EDIT: I also ran the following registry script to disable the action
of the <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> keys:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,00,00,49,e0,00,00,51,e0,00,00,00,00
```

But now it seems like AHK too won't accept <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> keys, even if Windows won't.

The idea is to only let AHK get the input.

Comment: Remove the `~` from each hotkey. Anyway, I don't think your script is optimal in most cases. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow you to do what you described:

```
hotkey, $pgDn, keyDelayer
hotkey, $pgUp, keyDelayer

keyDelayer:
    sleep 3000
    thisHotkey := regExReplace(a_thisHotkey, "[^0-9A-Za-z]")
    while getKeyState(thisHotkey, "p")
        send {%thisHotkey%}
return
```

If <kbd>PgDn</kbd> or <kbd>PgUp</kbd> is held for under three seconds, nothing happens. Once <kbd>PgDn</kbd> or <kbd>PgUp</kbd> is held for three seconds, the key begins repeatedly sending itself until it is released.